# How to create a standard error buffer around a regression line in a scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, regression, scatter-plot, standard-error

First time asking a question on the site, so please let me know if I am not providing enough detail. I currently have a scatterplot output from R with three regression lines for three separate treatments. I am hoping to include the standard error in this figure, however with over n>100 for each treatment, adding standard error bars for each data point makes it extremely hard to read the figure. I am trying to recreate something like the picture I attached, where the transparent buffers around the regression line would be the standard error around the regression line. This would all be done in R studio.

I don't know if this is at all possible, but if anyone has created a figure like this in the past and knows the coding to create it, please let me know.

Again, let me know if I can clarify in any way.

I have checked this site, as well as other R coding support networks for potential commands to get this sort of figure, but haven't found anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want: adding by group a regression line to your scatter plot and shaded confidence bands.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=factor(cyl), shape=factor(cyl))) +
         geom_point() + 
         geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

[image]